# HTML5 Webcam Stream broke somehow

Tags: javascript, html, streaming, html5-video, webcam

I have an extremely simple javascript that streams content from the user's webcam to an HTML5 video element. **It was working perfectly before I began today.** I was attempting to add a canvas element to the same page, and in doing so added a width and height specification to the video element so that the video and canvas would be the same size. Somehow this broke the webcam/video, so I reverted the changes... and its still broken.

So far I've tried clearing all browser data (I'm working in Chrome), restarting the browser, restarting the computer, and re- (and rere-, and rerere-) uploading the file, to no avail. I didn't touch the javascript at all, just the html5 above it, so I suspect this is an html5 issue, but I'm a rank beginner in javascript, so what do I know? Just getting this to work originally took awhile due to my inexperience, and now I've backslid even further with this development. What have I done, and how do i fix it?

Here's the code (Note: using Modernizr to handle the cross-platform stuff for getUserMedia):

```
<div id="webapp_content">

    <h4>Webcam Test</h4>

    <p>
    <div id="video_container">
        <video id="video_element" autoplay="true"></video>
    </div>

    <script>
    var video = document.querySelector('#video_element');

    if (Modernizr.getusermedia) {
        var gUM = Modernizr.prefixed('getUserMedia', navigator);
        gUM({video: true}, videoInit, videoError);
    }

    function videoInit(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    }

    function videoError(e) {
        alert('Error! getUserMedia not available!', e);
    };

    </script>

    <p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Do you receive any error messages ?

Comment: No, nothing. The video element is just a static gray box. I've also verified that it's not the browser nor the webcam, since other webpages out there that stream webcam to video elements (namely, tutorials) are working just fine.

Comment: The `autoplay` attribute is a boolean attribute. It is either absent or `autoplay`/`autoplay="autoplay"`.

Comment: does it ask you for permission to use the camera?

Comment: @IgorGilyazov: I've tried it all three ways, autoplay alone, with the true specified, and with quotes around the true. I've seen all three used interchangeably in others' code, and all three fail to make a difference in my code working or not. I've never seen "autoplay="autoplay"" before, but just for kicks I just tried it, and that doesn't work either.

Comment: @brianchirls: No, it doesn't. It used to (back when it worked), but now it's as though the script doesn't even exist.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the camera permissions? https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767

Comment: @brianchirls: Thank you for all your help! By all appearances there isn't a way to "reset" the camera permissions unless you've previously written a specific exception for a site, which I hadn't done for my page. Just to be sure though, I tried removing everything in the "manage exceptions" menu, and switched the media permissons to disallow all, and then back again. No luck - my video element remains stubbornly gray.

Comment: I really doubt whether the Modernizr.getusermedia is undefined. Have you checked it?

Comment: @yushulx: You're correct in your doubts; Modernizr is indeed defined, above the snippet I posted here. To be sure, I redownloaded it and replaced the file. It's still broken.

Comment: @xrmaxwell If you Deny permission once, then a rule should be set up and it won't ask you again. But you'd see the error on the console. Do you want to post the whole code somewhere online so we can try it out?

Comment: @yushulx As it happens, Modernizr WAS the problem... and actually, it WAS undefined. Explanation is in the Answer. Thanks for your help, it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually was with the Modernizr script: apparently sometime between now and when I first started using it, the Modernizr folks made the getusermedia portions of their code non-core, and thus was not included in their standard download.

I'm not sure whether this was the original problem, or whether my downloading the newest version of Modernizr created another problem on top of the original, but removing Modernizr from the equation solved the issue. I now have a working webcam stream again - albeit only in Chrome. I'll worry about cross-platform stuff later.